# Regex: Exclude a mix of fixed and unknown length pattern

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like this:

```
'Global Software Version (DID 0xFD15): 4.5.3'
```

And I want to find:

```
4.5.3
```

The string does always start with `Global Software Version`, but `(DID 0xFD15)` is a variable part, it is different each time.

**What I did:**

```
>>> x = 'Global Software Version (DID 0xFD15): 4.5.3'
>>> re.search('(?<=Global Software Version ).*', x).group().split(':')[1].strip()
'4.5.3'
```

Anybody with a better idea? Only with regex?

Comment: why not `'Global Software Version (DID 0xFD15): 4.5.3'.split(":")[1].strip()` ? I don't dare post an answer as simple as that as you clearly have the skills to figure it out yourself :)

Comment: Actually, the answer is in the question - `.split(':')[1].strip()`.

Comment: Any reason for not using `(\d\.){2}\d`. (Not sure it's Python style regex, anyway.)

Comment: May be I should have mentioned. The above line is a part of a big string. That's why you need to find first the fixed part. (Occurrence is guaranteed to be only 1).

Answer (score 1):

So you can do multiple things here. The easiest solution would be:

```
>>> x = 'Global Software Version (DID 0xFD15): 4.5.3'
>>> version = re.search('\d+[.]\d+[.]\d+', s).group()
>>> version
'4.5.3'
```

But this would also work:

```
>>> version = 'Global Software Version (DID 0xFD15): 4.5.3'.split(":")[1].strip()
>>> version
'4.5.3'
```

Hope this helps!